# Webpack Otimização de Minificação

Tags: desempenho, webpack

Estou iniciando com o **Webpack** e estou aprendendo como mexer no **Config** dele, e vi uma parte da documentação que trata à respeito de `Resolve.extentions`, achei bem legal porque você consegue ocultar as extensões. Mas me veio à cabeça: Nos meus imports eu coloco por exemplo:

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
```

Neste caso agora eu coloco apenas:

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery'
```

E ele funciona numa boa. Beleza. Mas ele está pegando o `.js`, e não o arquivo minificado. Faz alguma diferença em termos de performance ele pegar o `.js` ou `.min.js`? Como o Webpack trata esse tipo de arquivo? Tem que colocar algum *Priority* para ele pegar primeiro os `.min.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Faz alguma diferença em termos de performance ele pegar o .js ou
>   .min.js?

Sim, faz muita diferença. O arquivo minificado, como o próprio nome diz, é menor, e isso gera diferença de performance quando o site vai carregar as dependências, porque um arquivo menor é carregado e interpretado mais rápido.

> Tem que colocar algum Priority para ele pegar primeiro os .min.js ?

Você pode colocar na configuração do [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions), algo semelhante a:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.min.js', '.js']
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Lucas! Então quer dizer que as `extensions` que você vai colocar primeiro, são as que serão priorizadas?

Comment: Exatamente @Jackson!

Comment: Ótimo Lucas, muito obrigado :) ! Vou aproveitar e já colocar meus CSS minificados em prioridade também ;)

Comment: Para produção é o mais adequado, pelo melhor desempenho. Só pra desenvolvimento que pode não ser, porque o processo de minificação renomeia todas as variáveis e remove os espaços, dificultando o *debug*.

Comment: Sim, disso eu sei Lucas, eu tenho um `if NODE_ENV== Production`. De qualquer forma fica para aqueles que vierem visitar minha pergunta! Valeu =)